# environment first or boot first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initialization

environment.rb starts with this:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.2' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
```

Does this mean environment.rb starts first and calls boot.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment.rb is the main Rails environment file. It requires the boot.rb file but the boot.rb is run before Rails::Initializer.run. In fact, the last line of boot.rb contains the following statement

```
# All that for this:
Rails.boot!
```

Please note that while the environment.rb file belongs to your Rails app, the boot.rb file is automatically updated each time you run the rake task

```
rake update:rails
```

You should never modify that file.

To better understand how Rails initialization works, Sven wrote a really helpful article called [The Rails startup process from a paragliders perspective](http://www.artweb-design.de/2007/12/2/the-rails-startup-process-a-paragliders-perspective).